# PL/SQL Developer crear conexión sin modificar el tnsnames.ora

Tags: oracle, plsql

Existe la posibilidad que pueda crear una conexión a una base de datos Oracle, en PL/SQL Developer sin modificar el tnsnames.ora?
La razón es que no tengo permisos para modificar el archivo y debo crear una conexión totalmente nueva a la que sí tengo acceso por ejemplo, por telnet.

Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: En SQL Developer se pueden crear las conexiones sin usar el tnsnames.En el listado de conexiones, se crea una nueva, se ponen los datos y ya está.

Comment: Creo que estás confundiendo Oracle SQL Developer, con PL/SQL Developer. En este segundo es donde no logro hacerlo